# c# - How to convert from int to short?

Tags: c#, type-conversion

Doing an exercise where the output is different from the input.

For example if I input the number "6" into the console the output will be 54. What is the reason behind the output and how could I get the same numer as input?

```
    {
        int intVal;
        short ShortVal;

        intVal = Console.Read();
        ShortVal = (short)intVal;

        Console.WriteLine("{0}", ShortVal);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in the documentation for [`Console.Read`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.read?view=net-6.0):

> Returns [...] The next character from the input stream, or negative one (-1) if there are currently no more characters to be read.

It is written a bit sloppily, because technically it returns the Unicode character code of the character.<sup>[1]</sup>

If you type in the character `6`, what is the ordinal Unicode character value for this character? It's [54](https://unicode-table.com/en/0036/) (hex 0x0036; think of ASCII codes, but the encoding not being ASCII but rather Unicode). And that's precisely what you are seeing/getting here.

If you want to get the numeric value of the digit the character is representing (which is **not** the same as the numerical Unicode character code), take a look at the Unicode character codes for the characters `0`...`9`. They occupy the character code range from 0x0030 (for the '0' character) to 0x0039 (for the `9` character). It shouldn't be hard to notice that you could simply subtract the Unicode character code of the `0` character to get the value of the digit these characters represent:

```
intVal = Console.Read();

if (intVal < '0' || intVal > '9')
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not a numerical digit.");
}
else
{
    var digitValue = intVal - '0';
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", digitValue);
}
```

Now, this hopefully helps furthering understanding of character codes. However, the example code i have given here could be written differently, as the `char` type has a convenient method which provides the digit value of characters which represent digits (or represent numerical values, like roman numerals for example):

```
intVal = Console.Read();

if (intVal <= -1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("No character entered");
}
else
{
    var digitValue = char.GetNumericValue((char) intVal);
    if (digitValue < 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Not a numerical digit.");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", digitValue);
    }
}
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> If the method were to return a character, its return type would be `char` and not `int`. Although, the `char` type can be converted/cast to a numeric value such as `int` or `short` and back to get a characters Unicode character value and vice versa, so this distinction of characters vs. Unicode character code values seldomly matters in practical situations. However, here it may be useful to make this distinction to get a better understanding of what you observed.

Comment: Ok! Thank you for the explanation. How should I do to make the output the same as the input? Could you write some sample code?

Comment: @lucas17create, oops, i totally forgot to address this part of your question. I have added to my answer. Please look at it again...

Comment: No worries, thanks for the further explanation! :) Now the question becomes: How can we apply this to a random number with up to four digits, while converting from an int to a short?